# Pan over an image like a map using scroll container in godot?

Tags: gui, godot

I want to create a level select screen, the aspect ratio for my game screen is 576*1024 and the image, I am using is 2048*2048. What I want is for the user to scroll the screen and navigate along the path to select levels. I know how to implement just horizontal or vertical scroll, but, for this one, I want the user to be able to scroll in every direction like a map. Can anyone suggest the node setup in the scroll container for that?[image]

Comment: Probably easier ParallaxBackground, ParallaxLayer with motion_scale set to 1, and camera 2D. Then you can move the camera.